# axios.post.then() is ignoring the then() part for some reason

Tags: javascript, axios

I have this function...

```
function waterCalibrator() {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/update-water", {
    waterValue: props.moisture
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log("Water calibration worked")
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
    props.airValueObject.setWaterFlag(true);
    props.airValueObject.setWaterValue(props.moisture);
}
```

Can anyone explain why then() is not ever triggered? I have no errors. It simply isn't triggering. Everything works except for this...

```
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log("Water calibration worked")
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

server side looks like this...

```
app.post("/api/update-water", (req, res) => {
    const waterValue = req.body.waterValue;
    const sqlUpdateWater = "UPDATE user SET waterValue=? WHERE uid='j' ";
    db.query(sqlUpdateWater, [waterValue], (err, result)=>{
        console.log(`water is: ${waterValue}`)
    })
})
```

Comment: If the `then` isn't triggered and the `catch` isn't either than the promise never resolves... No?!

Comment: try using async/await ?

Comment: It should. Open up the Network tab of your DevTools, and check what happened to the request...

Comment: it give a status of 204

Comment: your code is fine, seems like you are requesting something thats not available ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a [204 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204), which means the request went through successfully but there is no content at all, hence you are trying to log nothing.

> The HTTP 204 No Content success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded, but... The common use case is to return 204 as a result of a PUT request, updating a resource, without changing the current content of the page displayed to the user. If the resource is created, 201 Created is returned instead. If the page should be changed to the newly updated page, the 200 should be used instead.

You also need, as suggested in previous comments, open the dev console and check the status of the promise itself. This promise seems to be successful.

If this answer helps solving the issue, **consider** accepting the answer or upvoting it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this in a few hours when I get home and let you know if this resolves it. It is entirely possible.

Comment: I assume you did not check if the answer solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry I had some other stuff going on. I am checking now and I will let you know.

Comment: So this was the issue. Thank you for your help. To clarify exactly why, I didn't have these 2 lines.....             res.send("Success"); res.end();                      So nothing was being sent back to the front end. Silly error.